# Bat file that affects all the files with the same extension?

Tags: file, command-line

Let's say that I have a .bat file that affects **One** specified file. But what I need is that it should affect all the files with the same extension. In my case, the extension is **.xxx**

This is the code I got so far. It works just on the file I type in. Right now it is **SND_MUS_Fanfares.xxx**

```
.\extract.exe -out=F:\cookedpc -filter=fmodeventfile SND_MUS_Fanfares.xxx
pause
```

So how do I change the code so it affects **a.xxx**, and **b.xxx**, and **c.xxx**, and **n.xxx** and so on ... ?

I'm new at all of this, so I can't even explain it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you know the 'for' command? Type 'for /?' details.

it would execute your command on every .xxx file in the directory:

```
for /R %I IN (*.xxx) DO .\extract.exe -out=F:\cookedpc -filter=fmodeventfile %~fsI
pause
```

Comment: It just wont work for me. Take a look at this screenshot please.
http://puu.sh/3A6Ud.png

Answer (score 1):

```
for %i in (*.xxx) do .\extract ... ventfile %i
```

should do that for you.

Double-up the `%`s if you have the sense to execute from a batch file rather than retyping the line every time...